# Is it possible to not use vim's small delete register?

Tags: vim

I'd like to have any deleted text *always* go into the numbered registers, but frequently I go to find something I deleted recently in the numbered registers and it's not there because it was less than one line.

> Numbered register 1 contains the text deleted by the most recent
>   delete or change command, unless the command specified another
>   register or the text is less than one line (the small delete register
>   is used then). With each successive deletion or change, Vim shifts the
>   previous contents of register 1 into register 2, 2 into 3, and so
>   forth, losing the previous contents of register 9.

It's a fairly rare thing, but when it happens, it's really annoying because I have to undo back to the point where I deleted the text, then either delete into a named register or immediately use the deleted text before it's out of register 0 because I delete something else (stray whitespace, bad comment, whatever) on my way to pasting the small text I just deleted.

I'd like the small delete condition not to matter for text entering the numbered registers 1-9.  Anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK this behavior can't be changed. But named registers are precisely designed to store stuff for later use and that's how you are supposed to roll. Alternatively, you could use the blackhole register (`"_`) to delete stuff you don't care about and keep your numbered registers clean. I have `nnoremap <leader>d "_d` and `inoremap <leader>d "_d` for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During [another such feature request on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/yyq4a/is_there_anyway_to_configure_vim_to_use_the/), it was found out that there was a bug in Vim that did exactly that when

```
:set clipboard^=unnamed
```

That bug [has been fixed](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/a5b378ac0c3c2e62/790351a16a7b88a4) in Vim 7.3.649. So, if you use an older version, you could still benefit from the bug :-)

If you really think this is useful behavior, you could raise this enhancement request on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php), though in general, additional options are frowned upon. Your chances are higher if you can make a compelling argument and also supply a complete patch with documentation and tests.

Comment: The vim_dev mailing list seems unavailable, isn't there a kind of a bug tracker?
I use neovim, don't you know whether there's such feature there?

Comment: @Himura The [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vim_dev) is currently active (at least I receive messages regularly); however, NeoVim is a separate project; you'll find it's bug tracker [over there](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues).

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I already found it and added an issue https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8121

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Pull Request into the **neovim** editor:

[[RFC] Add an option to use numbered registers for smaller deletions #8169](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/8169)

I've tried to add the `smalldel` option, which allows you to configure the minimum number of deleted characters to be pushed into the numbered registers "1.."9

The next neovim release after this PR is merged will contain this option.

Comment: Thanks for your work, I see that there has been some progress on the PR this year, I hope that it gets merged as soon as possible! :)