# Don't put character in yank buffer when pressing 'Del'

Tags: vim

Deleting a character in normal mode with <kbd>Del</kbd> places it the yank buffer. How can I change this behavior to keep the buffer unchanged? For example, yank it to the black hole buffer as one can when using the `d` command?

Comment: does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972203/is-it-possible-to-not-use-vims-small-delete-register

Comment: @Kent: it does not, unfortunately. The behavior is the same after issuing the ':set clipboard^=unnamed' command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the yank buffer with `"<character>`.  The "black hole" buffer is `_`, so the command you want would be `"_d` etc.  Note that this is per-deletion (yank, etc.).

You can create a simple shortcut in your `.vimrc` that does this with the <kbd>Del</kbd> by default.

```
nnoremap <Del> "_x
```

Comment: The author knows about this.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is to change the behavior of the 'Del' key in normal mode, not that of the 'd' command...

Comment: @rainer you could write something like `nnoremap <Del> "_x`

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! If you edit yor original answer, I can accept it :)